# Wordpress Multisite .htaccess .. please explain the functionality

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wordpress

**What is this .htaccess file doing??? I don't know anything about .htaccess .please help.**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
```

This turns on the rewrite engine, all the rules get ignored if this isn't in the htaccess file

```
RewriteBase /
```

This tells the rewrite engine that relative URL-paths should use this as its base

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

This rule means: "If the request is `index.php`, then pass it through the rewrite engine and stop rewriting"

```
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
```

This rule matches against `<some stuff>` then `wp-admin`, and redirects the browser to the same URL except it ends with a slash. Example: `http://example.com/foo/bar/wp-admin` gets redirected to `http://example.com/foo/bar/wp-admin/`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

This rule says if the request is for a file or directory that exists, pass it through the rewrite engine and stop rewriting.

```
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
```

This rule matches against `<some stuff>` then `wp-content` or `wp-admin` or `wp-includes`, and rewrites the URI to everything after the `<some stuff`> Example: `http://example.com/blah/blah/wp-admin/some/more` gets rewritten to `/wp-admin/some/more`.

```
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
```

This rule matches against `<some stuff>` followed by any php file, and rewrites the URI to everything after the `<some stuff>`. Example: `http://example.com/abc/123/somefile.php` gets rewritten to `/somefile.php`.

```
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Finally, if none of the other rules got applied, this rule rewrite everything else to `/index.php`.